# How to create a local HTML page in phone gap

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, cordova

I am doing the application in phone gap,But I have a problem that for switching the view,I dont know how to create a another view. But when I google it I get some relevant informaion like, I have create a local html file and then using the htmlcode i can switch the view.

If any one is having any relevant information regarding this please give me  some idea.

Answer (score 0):

My method for doing this is using ajax to load in my other pages. Essentially I have multiple html files and my main UI. When a button is clicked I fire an ajax request to load that new page and then animate it in using CSS animations ( which get hardware accelerated ).

remember to load the new page's data into a container div, so the rest of your UI can stay put.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate HTML file for a separate view and use JQuery for functionality. Suppose that when you click on button, just redirect to another HTML file or whatever your need is.